# Copy current executable to another path C++ (Windows only)

Tags: c++, copy, getmodulefilename

I forgot how to program in C++, I want my exutable to copy itself to another path. I found a code that do what I want to do but there are conversion error that I don't know how to resolve :

```
void Victim::replicate()
{
  char filename[ MAX_PATH ];
  char newLocation[]="C:\\Users\\myUsername\\Desktop\\";
  BOOL stats=0;
  DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameA( NULL, filename, MAX_PATH );
  CopyFile(filename, newLocation, stats);
      
}
```

I got an error while using the **CopyFile** function, It expect LPCWSTR type for **filename** and **newLocation** But if I declare those variable as **LPCWSTR**, the **GetModuleFileNameA** function will not work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your project is set to use the `W` versions of the API functions by default.
You override that by calling the `A` (Ansi) version of `GetModuleFileName`. Don't - or do, but then you also need to call `CopyFileA`.

Forcing Ansi version usage:

```
void Victim::replicate()
{
  char filename[ MAX_PATH ];
  char newLocation[] = "C:\\Users\\myUsername\\Desktop\\";
  BOOL stats=0;
  DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameA( NULL, filename, MAX_PATH );
  CopyFileA(filename, newLocation, stats);     
}
```

Forcing Wide version usage:

```
void Victim::replicate()
{
  wchar_t filename[ MAX_PATH ];
  wchar_t newLocation[] = L"C:\\Users\\myUsername\\Desktop\\";
  BOOL stats=0;
  DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameW( NULL, filename, MAX_PATH );
  CopyFileW(filename, newLocation, stats);     
}
```

Going with the project default:

```
void Victim::replicate()
{
  TCHAR filename[ MAX_PATH ];
  TCHAR newLocation[] = _T("C:\\Users\\myUsername\\Desktop\\");
  BOOL stats=0;
  DWORD size = GetModuleFileName( NULL, filename, MAX_PATH );
  CopyFile(filename, newLocation, stats);     
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and its clear now. I have to familiarize myself with all those type

Comment: @Flamecube667 Great! You're welcome! Regarding the types, I think one should use macros for `char` and `wchar_t` too, to be properly Microsoftified but I don't remember them :)